# GeoJSON path using d3

Tags: leaflet, geojson, path

I've been trying to make an animated path using d3, JSON, and a list of coordinates.

This is the result in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5m35J/92/

As you can see, there is a red dot in the corner, but the animation is stopped. I do not know if the geographic information is correctly loaded.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
var json, map,
path, vis, xy,
duration, offset, origin_x, origin_y, len, group, circle;

json = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                [-100.934121, 21.159216],
                [-100.807746, 20.527743],
                    [-101.427837, 20.951976],
                    [-101.257851, 21.018937],
                    [-101.189444, 19.768333],

            ]
        }
    }]
};

// Draw a GeoJSON line on the map:

map = $('#map');
xy = d3.geo.mercator().scale(12000).center([21.159216, -100.934121,]).translate([630700, 401100]);
path = d3.geo.path().projection(xy);

vis = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 600);

vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "route")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("fill", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke", "#333");

// Draw a red circle on the map:

group = vis.append("svg:g");

var targetPath = d3.selectAll('.route')[0][0];
var pathNode = d3.select(targetPath).selectAll('path').node();
var pathLength = pathNode.getTotalLength();

circle = group.append("circle")
    .attr({
    r: 10,
    fill: '#f33',
    transform: function () {
        var p = pathNode.getPointAtLength(0)
        return "translate(" + [p.x, p.y] + ")";
    }
});

// Animate the circle:

duration = 10000;
circle.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease("linear")
    .attrTween("transform", function (d, i) {
    return function (t) {
        var p = pathNode.getPointAtLength(pathLength*t);
        return "translate(" + [p.x, p.y] + ")";
    }
});
```

});